# What is the meaning of "must" in the sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

I have a sentense e.g. "White people are statistically shorter than black people, so they must be worse in basketball."

Ignoring if the sentence is true or not, how do you understand the function of must? Implication (possibility) or imperative?

Answer (score 1):

This *must* expresses logical necessity: you infer from their height that white people will be less capable, and you are convinced that this inference is certain.

By the way: the technical terms are *epistemic* (your 'possibility') and *deontic* (your 'imperative').

Answer (score 0):

It is used as an implication, however it comes with a stronger sense, as in the implication is bound to be correct and logical.